# Ubuntu 12.04.2 - OEM installation - UEFI mode

Tags: installation, grub2, dual-boot, uefi, oem

I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 in a laptop with a Windows 8 preinstallation in UEFI mode.

I followed the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) and I use a **64bit iso of 12.04.2**.

When I boot from USB (in UEFI mode) **the OEM installation is not availble** (there are only 3 options: "try ubuntu, install ubuntu and check disk", while if I boot the same iso in legacy mode the OEM installation is availble through the F4 options.

Also note that the 13.04 has availble the OEM installation from booting in UEFI mode.

It is important to install the LTS version because we prepare an image for use in >500 laptops and also we can not ignore the UEFI mode because we must have the dual boot with the existing Windows 8 preinstallation.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It seems this question is specifically about the OEM installation. They're related, but it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: Also the alternate iso of the same version do not have this option (OEM installation)

Answer (score 2):

Install Ubuntu like you would as a normal single user.
You can then install **oem-config-gtk**, which gives you the same features as an oem installation. Just install and configure everything the way you like and launch the **oem-config-gtk** at the end.

After restart, you will see the configuration dialog for new users.

One note: On my testing installation I used the user name **oem**. I don't know if this is important, but just to be safe I recommend to use this username too.

Comment: You have earned the bounty because you.. at least, answered.